# Trying to make a clock

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code , i have been trying to see why it's not working but i couldn't find mistake.

```
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;
var p = document.getElementById("p");
function clock() {
    sec++;
    p.innerHTML = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; 
    if (sec == 60) {
        sec = 0;
        min++;
    }
    if (min == 60) {
        min = 0;
        hour++; 
    }
};
window.setInterval(clock,1000);
```

Comment: "not working" is not a useful problem description. *How* is it not working? What do you see instead of what you expect?

Comment: Works as intended for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/bfRQH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your script is located or loaded inside the `<head>` of your document.

The browser parses the page from top to bottom. This causes the script to run before the rest of the document has loaded and your `<p>`-element does not exist yet. Your script has to wait until the document has been completely loaded so that the `<p>`-element is actually available to work with. To achieve this, simply use the `onLoad` event of the `window` object.

```
// This binds a function to a specific event.
// In our case, that's the onLoad event of the window object.
// The function gets called as soon as the entire document is done loading.
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hour = 0;
    // This line failed because an element with the ID "p" did not exist yet.
    // That's why you should wrap it in the onLoad event.
    var p = document.getElementById("p");
    function clock(){
        sec++;
        p.innerHTML = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; 
        if(sec == 60){
            sec = 0;
            min++;
        }
        if(min == 60){
            min = 0;
            hour++; 
        }
    };
    window.setInterval(clock,1000);
});
```

Comment: Nice opening explanation. But why use `load` rather than just putting the script at the end? `load` happens *very* late in the page load process. (Also note that IE8 doesn't have `addEventListener`, but still has a huge number of users...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. I used load because it's the most simple, self-explanatory, event-based approach that I know of. I tried to only answer the question without introducing additional problems like speed and browser compatibility. Moving the code to the bottom would have also worked, but I thought this would be a nice opportunity to introduce the OP to the way JS works with events.

Answer (score 3):

That code will only ever show `99` in the element, and it will only do that if the code is in a script tag *below* the element with the `id` value `p` in the HTML. (E.g., `<div id="p"></div>` or similar; note that `getElementById` gets an element by its `id` value, **not** its tag name.) This is because when `getElementById` is called, if the HTML of the element hasn't been parsed yet, the element won't exist, and so `getElementById` will return `null`.

To make it display something else, change

```
p.innerHTML = 99; // ...
```

...to something actually showing the values from `sec`, `min`, and `hour`.

Also note that the interval you give `setInterval` is only going to be approximate, so this clock will drift.

Here's a complete example, note where the `script` tag is in relation to the `div id="p"` tag, and the change I made to the line of JavaScript I mentioned above: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/AkIzIlet/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Partially-Fixed Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="p"></div>
  <!-- Notice how `script` is *below* the `div` above.
       In general, put `script` tags at the end of the
       HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag
  -->
  <script>
    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hour = 0;
    var p = document.getElementById("p");
    function clock() {
      sec++;
      p.innerHTML = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; 
      if (sec == 60) {
        sec = 0;
        min++;
      }
      if (min == 60) {
        min = 0;
        hour++; 
      }
    };
    window.setInterval(clock,1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't address the drift problem; I leave that as an exercise for the reader. The best bet there, if you want a "count up" timer, is to grab the date/time when your code starts:

```
var start = new Date();
```

...and then each time `clock` runs, get the total number of milliseconds that have passed since then:

```
var elapsed = new Date() - start;
```

...and do the math (1000 milliseconds per second, etc.) to figure out how long it's been.

Comment: _`setInterval` is only going to be approximate, so this clock will drift."_ - Good point. This is why something intended to display the actual time should use `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`) to trigger display updates, but use [`Date()` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to determine what time it is (or how much time has passed since the timer started).